# Facebook Like Button and app id?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate a facebook like button in my page. I created a facebook app and now I am wondering how the connection between app id and facebook like button works.

If you generate the like button code with the facebook tools:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

You get a button with just an url. I will place this button on my website. But how can I connect this now with my facebook app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select your app from the dropdown which appears if you click on "Get Code" on the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button website.

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBnxh.jpg

Comment: Ok I see. I was logged in with an user that had no app and therefore the dropdown did not show up. Thanks this helped me a lot.